# TypeScript: Interface across multiple types?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, casting

So I'm fetching data from an endpoint that is returning a collection of different types that all have the same interface…something like:

```
interface CommonInterface {
    public type: string;
    public commonProperty1: integer;
    public commonProperty2: boolean;
}

class Thing1 implements CommonInterface {}

class Thing2 implements CommonInterface {}
```

So then the endpoint returns `CommonInterface[]` which is a mix of `Thing1` and `Thing2` instances. One of the properties on `CommonInterface` is a `type` discriminator which identifies which "thing" it is.

How do I sort this typing structure out in TypeScript? How can I tell TS that an array is of type `CommonInterface`, but then tell it that the first item (based on the `type` value) is a `Thing1`, where the second item is a `Thing2`, and the third is a `Thing1`?

I've done some searching, but haven't found anything that really makes sense of this situation. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] that allows people to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Interfaces in TypeScript don't support `public` modifiers; `integer` is not a known type, and the above classes don't implement the interface.

Comment: @jcalz yes, the code I provided was not typescript but pseudo code of the classes/interface on the backend. I should have been more explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're given the following class definitions:

```
class Thing1 implements CommonInterface {
    readonly type = "Thing1";
    commonProperty1 = 1;
    commonProperty2 = true;
    thing1Prop = "okay";
}

class Thing2 implements CommonInterface {
    readonly type = "Thing2";
    commonProperty1 = 2;
    commonProperty2 = false;
    thing2Prop = "okay";
}
```

I'd be inclined to build [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to represent testing to see if a `CommonInterface` is a `Thing1` or a `Thing2` or something else.  It might look like this:

```
type Things = Thing1 | Thing2;
function isThing<T extends Things["type"]>(
    obj: CommonInterface, type: T
): obj is Extract<Things, { type: T }> {
    return obj.type === type;
}
```

And you might use it like this:

```
function processCommonInterfaceArray(objs: CommonInterface[]) {
    objs.forEach(c => {
        if (isThing(c, "Thing1")) {
            c.thing1Prop.toUpperCase();
        } else if (isThing(c, "Thing2")) {
            c.thing2Prop.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            // c is some other commonInterface
            c.commonProperty1.toFixed();
        }
    })
}
```

You can see from this that the compiler is use `isThing(c, "Thing1")` returning `true` to conclude that `c` must be a `Thing1` and therefore has a `thing1Prop`.  And that the same holds for `isThing(c, "Thing2")` and `Thing2`.  Because you can't be sure that all `CommonInterface` objects are definitely `Thing1` or `Thing2` (nothing stops someone from having a `Thing3` that implements `CommonInterface`), then you need to do something in with the last `else` clause.

---

Note that normally I'd expect you to use something like a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) of type `Things` and forget about `CommonInterface` entirely.  If you can refactor your typings so the endpoint returns `Things[]` instead of `CommonInterface[]`, then you don't need user-defined type guards to do control-flow narrowing:

```
function processThings(objs: Things[]) {
    objs.forEach(c => {
        if (c.type === "Thing1") {
            c.thing1Prop.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            c.thing2Prop.toUpperCase();
        }
    })
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2n0gJLjTxLIDeAsAFDI3JgCeADhAFzIDOYUoA5gNxVayBFhwgAClHTMoDAIxsQAV0wAjaAOq0R2XJOnQGAJjar06ADYQ4ITQF8qVBBbjt2yACoALXnOTBMRitMCHB3DF18QlhEFAotGihrABNcC3o6JhQAXmQAIm9fPM0hHTF9GXlkXLkS7VE9KUr6I2q6KCUIOpowHxAeOQq2vPQAazh6YqoHSicXN08+nlaAoIgQsLQGqMgYknihJLhUkHTM5mHC-qMphOFtisN6P1yjbvvIx9kWtvgLdi6glovV4RiGuRG40m9kclAYFyuPHcuURfgAPotQSUqDAlCAEGBgLh-OxEQAeDzICAAD0gIGS7kR7AA2nl4RA8gBdAB8AAogTR0KoAFZsCJiAi7YgQAA051YnioAEo2ELhSTkABRWlQRBgClLdhy0jytiUuzcsgC5BJMBKKAgZBqgB07Oq2Vy7Jhs0ouPxhOJjCkSDc4twkqIsQAglBdfReWr2GLthG9hBmZylVa7onnTB0FBNYgvLyENVLQchLRgDBkLzgKSlqW5QUlnI8kqs5Wq1WEK62xVXegAKqMGSoVwQXlK95COxU-4oGt1huI5v5RE3TvZns9vsg66DsAjsfQCcA6ez2jziCLne7oQAekfwg17CwKHQvWgHwl0Wl1oPn2ZSNAY3xyEOABiwDUhAySXoB17WnYSrTLCfoEkSjpBugIaNrw7AJiKSaYv0LKZvegrEXmBZFggJZltkFaITQy6lq6WTuhCqIdpRD7CP2vhHie46TghdxzguAJ8UBgmHk0Q6jqJF4zixyAzHOqGUHYQA)